# Use Excel Concatenate function

Tags: excel, concatenation

I am trying to merge the data from three columns into one column in Excel. Example, i would like to merge Product, Location, and Key_id into one column

```
Product Location             Key_Id
Car           VA             86421910
Car           VA             86424482
Car           VA             86416836

Combined Column:
Car 'VA', '86421910'
Car 'VA', '86424482'
Car 'VA', '86416836'
```

I was wondering if there is a way in Excel that can do it? Thanks in advance! I was not doing a good job of accepting the answers in the past. I will do my part which is to accept the answer moving foward.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.info-stat.com/XLConCat.htm shows examples of string concatenation in Excel.  If I knew which version you were using and could identify the column IDs I could write it.

Assuming Product is Column A, Location is Column B and Key_ID is column three and data starts at row 2:

```
=A2&" '"&B2&"', '"&C2&"'"
```

Comment: Thanks, Suirtimed. I am using version 2003.

Answer (score 1):

```
=CONCATENATE(A2," '",B2,"', '",C2,"'")
```