# Merge multiple cells in a single row in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I want to merge multiple cells in a **single** row.

Example:
Cells `A1` to `I1` contain numbers from 1-9.

Here, after merging I should get:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
in cell `J9`.

I tried `Concatenate` function in excel, but that does not work with a cell range.

There are other questions that have answers, but:

- I do not have `TEXTJOIN` enabled (Excel 2019 or O365)
- VBA scripting is not allowed

Is there another solution?

Comment: This one too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4513189/5468463

Answer (score 1):

If you have `TEXTJOIN()` function access then you can use below formula.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,A1:I1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put this formula in cell J9:

```
=A2&","&B2&","&C2&","&D2&","&E2&","&F2&","&G2&","&H2&","&I2
```